# How to include babel-polyfill with webpack multiple times?

Tags: node.js, webpack, babel-polyfill

Currently I have two different NPM components about to be webpacked, and both of them have `babel-polyfill` in their webpack entry point.

Now after bundling, I have two different bundle files, but requiring them in the same file would occur in an "babel-polyfill should be only required once" error.

Am I missing something, or is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on webpack but are you sure there is supposed to be two bundles? Bundle means everything together.

You could alsso try https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-runtime/ instead of `babel-polyfill`.

Comment: Thanks, using `babel-transform-runtime` is a good way around this, but my ultimate choice was to remove the `babel-polyfill` in the webpack entrypoint, and have the require `babel-polyfill` in a codebase that includes the two NPM components, so they can both use it.